# Official resource to download Stack Exchange site logos

Tags: support, logo

Is there an official resource from where high resolution logos for the various Stack Exchange network websites can be obtained? I am talking about logos of network sites that are launched and have a custom logo available and not looking for generic logo that sites have which is currently in beta.

I am aware of the [Logos and Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) page, but it contains icons only for a handful of main sites, such as Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User. Also, they do not contain the solid colored logos as seen on the landing screen of the Stack Exchange mobile apps.

It would be nice if both solid and full color variants are available. An example of what I am looking for:

[image] [image]

The logos would be used for **non-commercial purposes**. While it would be possible to scrape off the resources from corresponding webpages, I am interested in knowing if they are available through more formal means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'trilogy' (Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault), as well as Stack Exchange itself, we have the ['Logos and Icons' page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos). As far as I know, such a page does not exist for the other sites, but your 'scraping' solution works and the same [usage guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) will apply.

Comment: Thanks. I should have noted in the question that I became aware of the Logos and Icons webpage via a Web search. I was looking for a similar page(s) for other network sites. Good to know that same usage guidelines apply for scraped resources. Can you please edit the answer to include a URL containing legal text about site resource usage policy?

Comment: Sharing your research in the question always helps :) Also, you can find the guidelines on that very page, first sentence, but I'll include a link here as well.